# CentOS 5 kernel headers

Tags: c++, linux, header, centos, kernel

I need to use the "signalfd.h" (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) but my Linux distribution does not have this header file.

To get this header, I suppose I have to install the Linux kernel headers. Which kernel version include this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signal file descriptors were first implemented in Linux kernel 2.6.22, and glibc 2.8.

Your CentOS5 distribution runs kernel 2.6.18, and glibc 2.5. Your distribution is too old to support signal file descriptors. This is the reason you do not have this header file. You need to update to a newer release of CentOS.

Comment: You can always compile and install your own kernel, then reimplement the corresponding parts in glibc. But, it's easier to just upgrade.